# How to convert HH:MM:SS string to datetime?

Tags: c#

I am having an input string of **HH:MM:SS** for example **15:43:13**.

Now, I want to convert it to datetime but keep just the hour/time without the date etc.

Is it possible?

For example:

```
string userInput = "15:43:13";
DateTime userInputTime = Convert.ToDateTime(userInput);
```

Will it give me the full date including the year etc. ?
Is there any way to convert it to just **HH:MM:SS** without trimming/substring?

Comment: That's called a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: You can't. A `DateTime` requires a date component which you have not provided. If you want to represent a length of time, use `TimeSpan`.

Comment: First of all, it's "HH:mm:ss". Second, that method can infer a 0-value for the time, but it needs something to use for the date, since DateTime values _always_ have both date and time components.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others have said, it's a `TimeSpan`.

You can get a datetime by doing this

```
string userInput = "15:43:13";
var time = TimeSpan.Parse(userInput);
var dateTime = DateTime.Today.Add(time);
```

Comment: Or `TimeSpan.Parse(userInput, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` if the local culture might be "strange" (for example expecting `"15.43.13"`).

Comment: If the local culture is "strange" the odds are that the user also enters the format as required. But your example works great for storing and retrieving time from other source (like a DB)

Answer (score 2):

To just get a time span, you can use:

```
TimeSpan.Parse("15:43:13")
```

But you should ask yourself why you want to do this as there are some fairly significant gotchas. For example, which 2:33 AM do you want when it's Sunday, November 3, 2013, and daylight savings time is ending? There are two of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the extra data (year etc.) use `TimeSpan`
You can convert from the user input to a TimeSpan using `Timespan.Parse`

for example:
`TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse("6:12"); //06:12:00`

Read more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx