# How do I get the total hours worked for this list of employees (and hours worked is a string)?

Tags: c#, timespan

How do I get the total hours worked for the following list of employees?

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/56boHX)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        List<Employee> list = new();
        list.Add(new Employee{EmployeeName = "Test1", HoursWorked = "2:30"});
        list.Add(new Employee{EmployeeName = "Test1", HoursWorked = "3:30"});
    }
}
    
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    
    public string HoursWorked { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert HH:MM:SS string to datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525493/how-to-convert-hhmmss-string-to-datetime)

Comment: Why would `HoursWorked` be a `string` in the first place? Do you have control over that? If so, change it. Either make it a number or else use `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`TimeSpan.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netframework-4.8) to convert your `HoursWorked` string into a [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) and accumulate it for all employees.

Then you can use the [`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalhours?view=netframework-4.8) property to get the final value you need.

**Complete Example:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Employee
{ 
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string HoursWorked { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static double TotalEmployeeHours(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan();
        foreach (var emp in employees)
        {
            totalTime += TimeSpan.Parse(emp.HoursWorked);
        }
        return totalTime.TotalHours;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
        list.Add(new Employee { EmployeeName = "Test1", HoursWorked = "2:30" });
        list.Add(new Employee { EmployeeName = "Test1", HoursWorked = "3:30" });

        Console.WriteLine(TotalEmployeeHours(list));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

**Note:**
`TimeSpan.Parse` can fail and throw an exception if the string is not in the right format. In your real code you should handle this case properly. Alternatively you can use [`TimeSpan.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) which returns a `bool` upon failure.